# Winforms scrolling text control

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for a control that can hold a list of text items.

For example:

> Item 1
>
> Item 2
>
> Item 3

When I add a new item to this list (Item 4 for example), I want the new item to appear at the bottom of the list, and the other items to shift up 1 position. So in this example, adding Item 4, will mean that Item 1 will disappear from the list.

The reason I have not just gone with a listview is because I want the items to scroll up, like an animated transition if that makes sense?

Is there something out there that can do this, or should I be writing my own control?

EDIT: An example of a web based control:
http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/totem/index.html

EDIT 2: I'm also not after a horizontal marquee control.

Comment: why winForms and not WPF if you want animation?

Comment: My whole app is Winforms, unfortunately.

Comment: i think it is possibe, but it's gonna be messy, ichiy code, but start by searching "animate contor winforms"

Comment: This should work fine with a listview, have you even tried it? Just add a scrollbar to the view and let it scroll down every time you add an item.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a ListBox. It isn't exactly a beautiful solution, but adding to its collection and then either scrolling or setting the selected index to `ListBox.Items.Count - 1` works.

[Edit:] Oh right, animated. I believe the scrolling is animated if you set the selected index, but I doubt it will be satisfying if you are going for nice graphics.